# Why are the images noisy and low quality system wide? Why do the color profiles not activate?

Tags: nvidia, colors, image-viewers, photography

I'm relatively new to Ubuntu (12.04) and I'm now trying to decide if the system is usable for serious photography work. So far I love Unity and the snappiness of the system but there are some problems I can't resolve by googling.

My laptop has an integrated Intel HD 3000 and an nVidia 630M card (managed to be able to use it with Bumblebee)

1) Somehow the images shown in Darktable, Image viewer, etc. are really low quality, noisy and smudgy but clean and sharp in Windows on the same screen, same resolution. Every other thing looks nice, like movies and websites.

2) I have a calibrated profile for my screen and I've already added it in the system's color settings, set for all users also but does not activate. It would be especially needed for my external display which has too saturated reds thus unusable for work now.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I've grown to love Ubuntu and would be really happy to be able to use it for work.

Answer (score 2):

You might be dealing with a [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=665897) that affects image scaling in GNOME. There are alternative image viewers such as [Viewnior](http://xsisqox.github.com/Viewnior/) with a patched image library that fix the scaling issues.